# Difference between options in “branches to merge”

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When i merge my branches to master branch with intellij-idea, there are two options in the “branches to merge”‘s checkbox， can anybody tell me [what's the difference between these two？](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0qG.png)， thanks！

Comment: The `origin/` is where that branch was *on the server* the last time your git client talked to the server. In most cases where you merge from that branch the two should point at the same commit but they doesn't have to. The other branch, the one without `origin/` is where your local repository says that branch is.

Comment: You mean ,in most cases,they are the same.if i check the one without origin/ what will happen?